# javascript regex un-match leading zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex which matches following numbers for me

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

returns true for following numbers

```
1.xx
0.xx
100
1,000
1000

10,000
10000
```

i want to change my regex to do not match 0.xx but match [1-9].xx

Comment: Why are you chaining a bunch of small questions about changing the requirements of this one regex? Just wondering, isn't there a specific requirement you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a negative lookahead at the start:

```
^(?!0\.)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
 ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sGlDwL/1)

It will forbid any value starting with `0.`. If there can be many leading zeros, add `+` after `0`: `(?!0+\.)`

Answer (score 1):

I have got this regex :

```
^(?!0+\.)(?:[0-9]{1,2}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)|(?:\.\d{1,2})|(?:\.x{2})?$
```

It works with your numbers